# F5 BigIP upgrade from 9.x to 10.x

Tags: load-balancing, f5-big-ip, upgrade

Having a few difficulties upgrading a Big IP 3400 from 9.4.8 to any version 10.x image.

The following are the versions I've tried:

10.1.0.3341.0
10.2.2.763.3
10.2.3.112.0
10.2.4.577.0

To upgrade I'm running the following command:

image2disk --format=volumes BIGIP-10.1.0.3341.0.iso

Obviously replacing the version number with the relevant image I'm trying to upgrade to each time.

The F5 reboots, and starts copying packages however after 30 seconds or so just stops copying. The cursor in the console is still flashing but no matter how long it's left, the package doesn't copy. It seems to be a different package with each version/image (but always the same package per version) at point of freezing, which I'm guessing is suggesting a space issue? I've checked free space on the device and it has over 2GB free at root which should surely be enough?

If anyone has any advice or pointers, it would be kindly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I had to wipe the F5 and start from scratch, making a bootable USB with the 10.2.4 image on. Once that had installed, you can setup the management IP and hostname (MUST BE IDENTICAL TO THE HOSTNAME OF THE CONFIG YOU WANT TO RESTORE), log in to the management interface and restore the config.